# VS2013 Code Analysis Custom Dictionary Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I'm trying to use visual studio's code analysis feature. Unfortunately (or fortunately?), I live in Canada and the code analysis complains about my spelling of the word "colour". I'm trying to use a [custom dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx) but VS2013 seems to be ignoring it.

Here's the location of the dictionary relative to the project (and solution):

[image]

Here's the content of the dictionary file:

```
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Unrecognized>
      <Word></Word>
    </Unrecognized>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>colour</Word>
    </Recognized>
    <Deprecated>
      <Term PreferredAlternate=""></Term>
    </Deprecated>
    <Compound>
      <Term CompoundAlternate=""></Term>
    </Compound>
    <DiscreteExceptions>
      <Term></Term>
    </DiscreteExceptions>
  </Words>
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym></Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

I've also tried culling down the content of the custom dictionary to:

```
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>colour</Word>
    </Recognized>
  </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

Does anyone know what's going on and how I can fix this?

Comment: Heretical though it may seem, I've reluctantly accepted that when it comes to programming, (US)Americanisms are a fact of life. You're going to introduce noise and ambiguity if you introduce regional words to a system that is most definitely US spelling oriented. Now I curse when I see the word "Colour" in programs. What have I become????

Comment: We'd like to thank all y'all fer yer adoptin of our language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a custom dictionary for this.  Instead, if you're using Canadian spellings consistently in your code base, you can use the [`CodeAnalysisCulture` MSBuild property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/08/12/new-for-visual-studio-2008-spelling-rules.aspx) to specify use of `en-CA` as the language in which spelling rules should operate. *e.g.*:

```
<CodeAnalysisCulture>en-CA</CodeAnalysisCulture>
```

---

In order for Visual Studio to recognize the custom dictionary make sure you set the build action on the XML file to `CodeAnalysisDictionary`. See this page for more info: [To apply a custom dictionary to a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-customize-the-code-analysis-dictionary#BKMK_ToApplyACustomDictionaryToAProject)

Comment: This does solve my problem but doesn't answer my question. Would you happen to know what's going on with the custom dictionary?

Comment: Have you set the build action for the custom dictionary file to `CodeAnalysisDictionary` (as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx#BKMK_ToApplyACustomDictionaryToAProject)?